# How to open 8-pin Mini-DIN female connector?

Tags: connector

I have a female connector that looks like this.

[image]

I want to use it in the panel of my product, so I have to remove the outer black sheath. Any tips on how I do it?  I can't get it to open.  Even to solder a wire into it, I need to open it, and I have no idea how to do it...  I'm guessing it'll look something like this once its opened.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an exacto knife and keep scoring the outside surface (just above the forward arrow). Eventually you will get through the plastic and will be able to pull the sheath back and have access to the pin-out. If you are impatient like me you could use a dremel but you may completely destroy everything in the process.

Comment: To be clear, I am to scratch out the outer surface with the knife? Or should I just make a circular cut to pull out the sheath?

Comment: A circular cut around the sheath. Just keep going around with your knife until you've cut through the plastic. The pull the entire sheath off the back.